# TF-IDF features of different dimension

Tags: machine-learning, svm, natural-language

I have different sentences and I am trying to perform TFIDFVectorizer with a word level n-gram on them. The problem is that they all are giving me different dimension of sparse matrix. The sentences are from different users.

So it means that user1: sentences has 10*3 matrix while user 2: sentences has 25*18 matrix and so on.

I have added user1 and user2 features in a list already.

I wanted to ask since, the dimensions are different (for the features), wouldn't it be a problem while performing classification on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a set (Vocabulary) that includes all the unique terms that you can find in all the sentences of your available dataset. After that you can compute the tf-idf weight for all the sentences(vectors) of your data.

Comment: Can I mix the words? they are from different users though.

Comment: Even if the answer is yes to above, how can I go ahead and get the words only as I am using TFIDF vectorizer which has n-gram built in. Later on I will perform character-level n-gram also etc. So that means that I will have to make another set for that as well. Hence, I am not sure if generating the set is the only solution. The point is that based on the comments the features dimension will always be different. Be it n-gram or any other sentiment analysis feature. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Can we use any other feature which will be length independent? Maybe I should get rid of TFIDF?

Comment: Of course you can mixed the words. Your model should include all the terms that you find in the available collection. Also tf stands for the term frequency and idf for the inverse document frequency, so you need to know if a term is included in other documents(sentences at your case). N-gram representation is considering n terms in a row instead of one single term and at this case you vocabulary will include all the n-grams instead of just single terms.